# simple sql issue

Tags: sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have tables

- **Product** (`ID, CategoryID, ...`)
- **Category** (`ID, Name, ..`), and
- **FieldValue** (`ID, ProductID, Value...` )

This is my query:

```
select count(*) from Product as p, FieldValue as v, Category c
where c.ID = 3 and v.Value="XXX"
and p.ID = v.ProductID and c.ID=p.CategoryID
group by p.ID
```

My intention is obvious to count the number of products with certain criteria.

The problem is NHibernate is returning me a list of numbers instead of a single number with the number of products. What am I missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remove the `group by`

With the statment you have, you get one count for each productID, instead of a count for all products.

If you want to count the number of products, replace the `count(*)` with `count(distinct p.id)` (still without `group by`)

Comment: So I have 6 products totally. If I remove the group by I get the result 35 wich is wrong. Because I have several FieldValues for the same product and a product is counted several times. So I need some kind of group by. Not sure how?

Comment: So what exactly do you want to count? The number of products? The number of fieldvalues per product? The number of products per category? The number of categories that have products?

Comment: The number of products. More exactly the number of products that match certain criteria.